# Assign a URL to Url.AbsoluteUri in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Can I assign a URL to `Url.AbsoluteUri` in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a read-only property.

You can create a new `Uri` though:

```
var url = new Uri("http://absoluteurl.example.com");
// url.AbsoluteUri is now "http://absoluteurl.example.com"
```

Comment: @Navin: the way to thank someone for their response is to click the "^" button to upvote their answer. Saying so in a comment just adds noise, and will likely be removed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. But you can create a Uri with the desire AbsoluteUri by constructing one:

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, it is derived from the URI. See the [MSDN documentation for Uri.AbsoluteUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx).

Example from MSDN

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri,"catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");
```